# Why does Mr Stabs come back in these three seemingly unrelated children's TV Series?

Tags: ace-of-wands, shadows, dramarama

[Mr Stabs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ace_of_Wands_(TV_series)#Off-shoots) is a recurring antagonist, only they recur between different TV Series:

> The character of Mr. Stabs, played by Russell Hunter, is defeated by Tarot in Series 2, returned, again played by Hunter, in a 1975 episode of the horror-themed children's anthology series *[Shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadows_(TV_series))* in the episode "Dutch Schlitz's Shoes" (Series 1, episode 6). This episode was also written by Trevor Preston. The character returned once more, this time portrayed by David Jason in a 1984 prequel story for another children's anthology series *[Dramarama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dramarama_(TV_series))*. This episode, simply entitled, "Mr. Stabs" was Series 2, episode 7 of the series and was again written by Preston.

Is there ever an explanation in any of the above TV shows, or by Trevor Preston himself why the character was shared by seemingly disparate universes?

Comment: Are they the same character or simply 2 different characters who share a name and do similar things in similar way for possibly similar reasons

Comment: @Revenant I can only go by the Wikipedia page, but it implies it's the same character.